# Transforming data from one form to another

Tags: elixir

I have the following list:

```
l = [
        %{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: "car"}, 
        %{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: "bike"}, 
        %{id: 2, name: "rahul", possess: "scooter"}
]
```

I want to convert this into the following format:

```
ans = [
        %{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: ["car", "bike"]},
        %{id: 2, name: "rahul", possess: ["scooter"]}
]
```

Any idea on how to do this in elixir? Since all the variables are immutable, I don't know how to achieve the above transformation.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use `Enum.group_by/3` with the mapper function (third argument) returning only the `possess` field.

```
[
  %{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: "car"}, 
  %{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: "bike"}, 
  %{id: 2, name: "rahul", possess: "scooter"}
]
|> Enum.group_by(&{&1.id, &1.name}, & &1.possess)
|> Enum.map(fn {{id, name}, possess} ->
  %{id: id, name: name, possess: possess}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[%{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: ["car", "bike"]},
 %{id: 2, name: "rahul", possess: ["scooter"]}]
```

Comment: This. I did not know about `Enum.group_by/3`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
l
|> Enum.group_by(fn %{id: id, name: name} -> [id, name] end)
|> Enum.map(fn {[k, v], m} ->
     %{id: k, name: v, possess: Enum.map(m, & &1.possess)}
end)
#⇒ [
#  %{id: 1, name: "aash", possess: ["car", "bike"]},
#  %{id: 2, name: "rahul", possess: ["scooter"]}
# ]
```

In a case of generic fields the solution would be slightly more complicated, involving [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) instead of [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) on the last step.